# Is there any difference in using !! vs using checks for null | undefined? in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was wondering if there is any difference when using `!` vs checks like `isNullOrUndefined` or even custom checks like

`customIsNullOrUndefined(obj: any) { return obj === null || obj === undefined;}`

vs

```
!obj
```

vs

```
util.isNullOrUndefined(obj)
```

I know that `util.isNullOrUndefined` is deprecated

I mean semantically !obj should return the same as the checks for null | undefined

Comment: Well `!obj` is *completely* different...

Comment: There are more than a few ways to check if an object exists, I prefer the simplicity of `typeof obj !=="undefined"`

Answer (score 2):

`!obj` will evaluate to `true` for any [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). That means `null` or `undefined`, but also things like `0` or `""`. You can use this if you're sure you're only checking objects and not primitive values.

Answer (score 0):

The not operator of `!` determines whether a value is falsy, which includes the following:

- `false`
- `0`
- `undefined`
- `null`
- `''`

If a function checks for `null` or `undefined`, then it will not check for other falsy values, such as `false`, for example.